# Why is pmap slower than map?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am trying to solve various systems of equations in parallel using pmap through the following code:

```
#A function that returns an invertible matrix.
function invertible_matrix(n)
  A=zeros(n,n)
  while true
    A=rand(-10:10,n,n)#ones(Float64,n,n)
    try
      Ai=inv(A)
      break
    end
  end
  return A
end
################################################################################
parallel=true#; parallel=false
N=100 # The number of systems of equations that need to be solved.
n=1000# The number of variables and equations.
A=invertible_matrix(n)

A=[A for i in 1:N]#We transform A into a list of copies of the matrix A
# We generate the solutions of the systems before hand.
x0=[[float(i) for j in 1:n] for i in 1:N]

# We generate the right hand sides of the systems.
b=[ A[i]*x0[i] for i in 1:N]

#We solve all systems either in parallel or in series.
if parallel
  x=pmap(\,A,b)
else
  x=map(\,A,b)
end

s=sum(x)[1]
#This should print 5050.
println(s)
```

This should solve 100 systems of equations with 1000 variables in parallel. If I use htop to monitor the use of my cores I can verify that running `$ julia -p 8 test.jl` does indeed use all of my processors, however it takes more time than using only one core with `$julia test.jl`! This are my trials

```
$ time julia test.jl 
5049.999977945663

real    0m27.934s
user    0m28.268s
sys 0m1.776s
$ time julia -p 8 test.jl 
5050.000001198174

real    0m39.169s
user    4m22.088s
sys 0m3.308s
```

And if I use map instead of pmap by setting `parallel=false` I get similarly faster results:

```
$ time julia test.jl 5049.999999852108

real    0m26.691s
user    0m27.140s
sys 0m1.612s
$ time julia -p     8 test.jl 
5050.000000001826

real    0m32.142s
user    0m49.284s
sys 0m2.064s
```

Why is this?

Comment: I don't think this does what you think this does. I believe it will solve the same linear system on each core. Also, you should do timing inside Julia, and not on global scope.

Comment: It is meant to solve systems of equations given by the same matrix `A` but different right hand sides `b` such that the corresponding `x` are vectors with all their elements equal to a number from 1 to 100 for each of the systems solved.

Comment: Like @DavidP.Sanders said, do the timing in Julia, with the `@time` macro, for example. Otherwise, you are also measuring the time to initialize all the workers, which by my experience is not small.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry, I didn't read carefully enough what the code was trying to do. If this is the actual goal (solving with lots of right hand sides) then you should probably be using LU decomposition or similar.

Comment: The end goal is to solve different systems of equations in parallel. This is just a proof of concept test.

Comment: I am calling it with `@parallel` twice now, and using `pmap` I get `33.931478 seconds (6.33 M allocations: 268.823 MB, 0.39% gc time)` and `28.808267 seconds (18.24 k allocations: 2.297 MB)`. But using map (with a single core) I get `25.674722 seconds (890.48 k allocations: 799.817 MB, 0.59% gc time)` and `25.128936 seconds (1.01 k allocations: 764.135 MB, 0.06% gc time)`. So apparently `pmap` is slower than `map`.

Comment: The communication between processes can be costly for big matrices, maybe if the matrices are generated at the nodes the speed advantage of parallelism would be larger. Note that for the single process case, the same `A` is used and thus enjoys unfair memory locality advantage.

Comment: But I do not expect any communication to occur between the procesess \ should act only on its local copy of A[i] and b[i], shouldn't it?